# How do you modify the matched string using Regex.Replace?

Tags: c#, regex

Say I want to convert these strings:

www.myexample.com and http://www.myexample.com
into:

```
<a href='http://www.myexample.com'>http://www.myexample.com</a>
```

using Regex.Replace

I've come up with this:

```
Regex.Replace(string, pattern, "<a href=\"$&\">$&</a>")
```

My problem is that I don't know how to check if the matched string $& starts with http:// and adds it if necessary.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the pattern you've been using?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to consider `https` or things like that, you could maybe use this:

```
Regex.Replace(string, @"(?:http://)?(.+)", "<a href=\"http://$1\">http://$1</a>")
```

Comment: If you wanted to consider the `https` possibility, then change the `http:` to `https?:`